# UL not displaying inline

Tags: html, css, haml, sass

I'm trying to make an unordered list to have inline display. I have the following haml:

```
%ul.nav-dashboard
  %li.orders_nav{:class => is_active_menu?(user_orders_path(params[:user_id]))}
    = link_to side_nav_title('Order'), user_orders_path(params[:user_id])
  %li.bucks_nav
    = link_to side_nav_title('Points'), user_points_path(params[:user_id])
  %li.billing_records_nav
    = link_to side_nav_title()..
```

here's the sass:

```
.nav-dashboard
  +list-reset

  a
    display: inline-block
    padding: 10px 13px 10px 19px
    color: #808080
    line-height: 21px
    font-weight: bold
    border-bottom: 1px solid $border-default
    font-size: $font-base + 1
    &:hover
      color: $text-medium
  .active a
    background-color: #f2f2f2
    +box-shadow(inset 0 0 5px 1px #ebebeb)
    color: $text-medium
```

For some reason, the three list elements are still displaying one on top of another, not next to each other. Any reason this could be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it `ul` you are trying to make inline? Or list items?

If the latter - you need to style the `li` elements, not the `a`

```
.nav-dashboard li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```